# Hatcher 4.2.19 homotopy group of skeleton of $K(G,1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, higher-homotopy-groups, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Let $X$ be a $K(G,1)$ which is a CW complex. We want to show that $\pi_n(X^n)$ is free (abelian when $n\geq 2$ where $X^n$ is the $n$ skeleton of $X$.

I thought I could choose any model for a $K(G,1)$ to prove my claim, but it turns out homotopic spaces don't necessairly have homotopic skeletons. And my ideas were based on that, hence I am quite lost.

I am thinking I should work instead on the universal cover, and then use the higher and higher connectdenss to allow an application of Hurecwiz which could lead to the desired result? I have yet to figure out if this idea can lead me to what I want. The (first) problem I am experiencing with this method is that it isn't clear that the $n$ skeleton of the universal cover is the universal cover of the $n$ skeleton.

Any method is accepted, I just wanted to share my ideas. Thank you.

Comment: I don't agree that homotopy equivalent spaces have equivalent skeletons, you can put a CW structure on $S^n$ with one zero cell, and one n-cell, OR you can use 2 cells in each dimension up to $n$, for example, these structures clearly do not have equivalent skeleta.

Comment: Mmh right, why did I miss that? Do you have any help for the rest of the question?

Comment: It's not so clear to me whether your approach yields the result, but the $n$-skeleton of the universal cover is indeed the universal cover of the $n$-skeleton of $X$ for $n\ge2$. First, a CW-structure on the universal cover $\pi\colon Y\rightarrow X$ is constructed by lifting the cells, so $\pi^{-1}(X^n)=Y^n$ and the induced map $Y^n\rightarrow X^n$ is automatically a cover. Since $n\ge2$, $\pi_1(Y^n)=\pi_1(Y)=0$, so $Y^n$ is simply connected and this cover is universal.

Comment: I'll see if I can get anything, but so far it isn't looking very promising

Comment: It might be easier to think in terms of homology groups and try to pass back via Hurewicz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that passing to the universal cover $+$ $n$ skeleton $+$ using Hurecwiz works.

Let $X$ be a $K(G,1)$, we want to show $\pi_n(X^n)$ is free abelian where $X^n$ is the $n$ skeleton of $X$. $X^n$ admits a universal cover, call it $Y^n$ which we can take to be the $n$ skeleton of $Y$ the universal cover of $X$ (Thank you Thorgott).

That being said we can see that $\pi_i(Y^n)\cong \pi_i(Y)\cong 0$ for $i\leq n-1$ where we used that $Y$ is contractible as the universal cover of an Eilenberg Maclane space. So $Y_n$ is $n-1$ connected, so we can use Hurecwiz to get $\pi_n(Y^n)\cong H_n(Y^n)$. Now because $Y^n$ has no $n+1$ cell we can see that $H^n(Y^n)$ is free with basis the $n$ cells of $Y^n$.

Chaining the isomorphisms together, we get the desired result
$$\pi_n(X^n)\cong \pi_n(Y^n)\cong H_n(Y^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}^K$$